# Datepicker OnClose() not working after form submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datepicker, thymeleaf

Below code is working fine for me. (OnClose of ValidFrom datepicker it should set minDate for ValidTo  and viceversa)

```
$( "#validFrom" ).datepicker({ 
      dateFormat : 'dd-M-yy', 
      changeMonth: true,
      changeYear: true,                                   
      onClose: function( selectedDate ) { 
        $( "#validTo" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", selectedDate );
      }
    }); 
$( "#validTo" ).datepicker({ 
      dateFormat : 'dd-M-yy',
      changeMonth: true,
      changeYear: true,
      onClose: function( selectedDate ) { 
        $( "#validFrom" ).datepicker( "option", "maxDate", selectedDate );

      }
    });
```

But after form submit, the functionality is not working. It is not setting mindate and maxDate as specified

Adding css and js being used:

`<script th:src="@{/js/jsDatePick.min.1.3.js}"></script>`
`<link th:href="@{/css/jquery.ui.datepicker.css}" rel=" stylesheet" />`

Javascript call on submit:

```
searchActionURL = function(obj) {

var atleastOneFilled = checkFields($("#searchForm")); 
$('#searchValidate').val(atleastOneFilled); 
$("#searchForm").attr("action", obj);    
if(atleastOneFilled)
{
    $("#searchResults").show(); 
}
else
{
    alert('Please specify one search item');
    return false;   
}
};
```

Comment: Which DatePicker library are you using? And could you add the HTML as well?

Comment: I have added it in the question

Comment: Thanks, I would like to know how your form submit works too.

Comment: On click of Search button, form gets submiitted. `<input type="submit" value="Search" id="search" class="btn btn-primary" th:onclick="'javascript:searchActionURL(\'' + @{/searchPersons/search} + '\')'" /> `. This calls a javascript function. Do you want me to add javascript call in question?

Comment: Yes please, every bit helps ;)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have edited the question with javascript call

Comment: Good, could you add some more? It is unclear to me what the `#searchValidate`, `#searchResults`, etc. are. Please show us all elements involved.